# Why Google Maps crashes with "Attempt to set an unknown enum value" error?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I use 3.1.0 version of Google Maps SDK for iOS. When assigning `view` to `GMSMapView` in `loadView` function, app crashes with following error: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'GMSx_GMMClientPropertiesRequestProto.screenPixelDensity: Attempt to set an unknown enum value (0)'`. It is really strange why it happens. I tried to downgrade version of Google Maps, but it didn't help. In `AppDelegate`, I provide `API_KEY`. Here is my code, how I use Google Maps:

```
lazy var mapView: GMSMapView = GMSMapView(frame: .zero)

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    view = mapView

}
```

What is the reason why this error occurs and how it can be solved?

UPDATE-1: 
I made a little experiment and tested in several devices with following simple code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mapView = GMSMapView()

    let dummyView = UIView()

    dummyView.backgroundColor = .purple

    view = mapView
}
```

This code successfully shows a map on iPhone 7, but fails with the same error on iPhone SE. Both devices running on iOS 12.3.1. It fails on initialising `mapView`, not on setting it to `view`. Even when I set `dummyView` to `view`, it crashes, because I initialised `mapView`.

UPDATE-2:
Tried to avoid initialising `mapView` variable myself. Created storyboard, added view and indicated that the class is `GMSMapView` and connected to my view controller. Removed all above code from VC. Worked in iPhone 7, failed in iPhone SE with the same error.

UPDATE-3: 
Created new project and used the same API_KEY to show maps. It worked in iPhone SE! It means, problem is not in device, it is in project. Still don't know where it is, but maybe in Pods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after the all updates above, I came up with an idea that I should delete the app in my phone and run it again. Then, it worked! I don't know why it has worked. Possibly, this error occurs only in debug version of the app.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, I reinstall the app it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I am using localization in my app and when I changed the languages, I was also adding the following code:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(lang, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

So by commenting it, and then reinstalling my app, it worked!